# Standard method to import and use animations in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, blender, maya, 3dsmax

I am about to hire a 3D artist to work on some animated models that will end up filling a 3D world made with OpenGL. What is the standard way of exporting animated models? If there's no standard way, could you list some options? I can't find any exhaustive reference about this subject. 
Also, is it equivalent if he will use 3DSmax, Maya or Blender, in terms of what is going to be possible to achieve and the complexity to achieve it with OpenGL?

Comment: Google assimp. There is no standard way, esp. not for animation. You should not hire someone before figuring out the tool chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Assimp` library can handle a lot of [3D model formats](http://www.assimp.org/main_features_formats.html). Like in the comment section was mentioned, there is no standard way. Their are a plenty of 3D model formats out there.  [This](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/) tutorial series is a good start learning `OpenGL`. Tutorial 22 and 38 is about 3D model loading and animation.